# Download file Apache FTP Android

Tags: android

I am download a file in android apache ftp client. Although I am not receiving error but warning in Logcat

Here is the code

```
public void downloadFile(String filename) {
        BufferedOutputStream desFileStream = null;
        try {
            desFileStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()),
                    8 * 1024);
            mFtp.retrieveFile(filename, desFileStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

And my stacktrace is

```
12-15 20:17:30.170: W/System.err(19182): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
12-15 20:17:30.180: W/System.err(19182):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
12-15 20:17:30.180: W/System.err(19182):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
12-15 20:17:30.180: W/System.err(19182):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
12-15 20:17:30.215: W/System.err(19182):    at com.murtaza.msftp.myftpTask.downloadFile(myftpTask.java:82)
12-15 20:17:30.220: W/System.err(19182):    at com.murtaza.msftp.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:74)
12-15 20:17:30.281: W/System.err(19182):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
12-15 20:17:30.281: W/System.err(19182):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
12-15 20:17:30.307: W/System.err(19182):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
12-15 20:17:30.320: W/System.err(19182):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
12-15 20:17:30.330: W/System.err(19182):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-15 20:17:30.330: W/System.err(19182):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-15 20:17:30.330: W/System.err(19182):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-15 20:17:30.330: W/System.err(19182):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-15 20:17:30.330: W/System.err(19182):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-15 20:17:30.340: W/System.err(19182):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-15 20:17:30.340: W/System.err(19182):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-15 20:17:30.340: W/System.err(19182):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-15 20:17:30.340: W/System.err(19182):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-15 20:17:30.359: W/System.err(19182): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
12-15 20:17:30.380: W/System.err(19182):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
12-15 20:17:30.380: W/System.err(19182):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:98)
12-15 20:17:30.380: W/System.err(19182):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
12-15 20:17:30.380: W/System.err(19182):    ... 17 more
```

After implementing

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+ filename
```

Giving Null Pointer Exception. StackTrace is

```
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296):    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.getRemoteAddress(SocketClient.java:651)
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:732)
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._retrieveFile(FTPClient.java:1778)
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.retrieveFile(FTPClient.java:1769)
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296):    at com.murtaza.msftp.myftpTask.downloadFile(myftpTask.java:85)
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296):    at com.murtaza.msftp.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:74)
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-15 20:47:26.350: E/AndroidRuntime(26296):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Now if you would just read your error-message: "/mnt/sdcard: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)" And your code uses this: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. This is only a path, not a file so it can't be opened.

Comment: I am not opening, I am downloading

Comment: @MurtazaHussain : use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` instead of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Answer (score 1):

The error-message states that:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: **/mnt/sdcard: open failed**: EISDIR (**Is a directory**)

In your code, you're doing this:

```
new FileOutputStream(
  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() // <- This points to /mnt/sdcard
);
```

Now, as the [`FileOutputStream`-documentation states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29):

> **Throws:**
>   *FileNotFoundException* - **if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file**, does not exist but cannot be created, or
>   cannot be opened for any other reason

So, use something like this for the argument:

```
new FileOutputStream(
  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+filename
);
```

This will create the a file with the name stored in `filename` on your SD-card and write into it.

Comment: Add the **full** StackTrace from the LogCat to your **question** (not in the comments!)